# How does Python to import this type of matlab formated data from a .txt file?

Tags: python, matlab

inside the txt file, the content is ready for matlab to consume and it can be run as a .m file:

% -----------------------------

Data(1, :) = [-2.875, 2.75, -1.0, -2.75, -0.875];

Data(2, :) = [-1.125, 2.625, 3.0, 1.25, 2.875];

How to import this data into Python as a data structure?

googled mathcad website and found nothing to help.

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to convert Matlab code to Python code, especially if this is all it contains.  Just a few minutes with a text editor should do it.

Comment: The actual file is 1000 times bigger...

Comment: Doesn't matter.  It's an easy transform.  How would you write the statement in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
import re

with open("test.txt", "r") as filestream:
    for line in filestream:
      sub_strings = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", line)
      if sub_strings:
        list_of_floats = [float(x) for x in sub_strings[0].split(",")]
        # do stuff with 'list_of_floats'
```

Here we read a text file "test.txt" line by line. In each line we're getting all sub-strings between two characters '[' and ']' (this is done using a regular expression). If we have found any: split the first sub-string (using comma as a delimiter) into a list of strings, and then convert it to a list of floats.

Of course, this chunk of code will work only if all lines of the file are in the same format (like in your example). Otherwise you'll have to do extra checks and skip all lines that you don't care about.